# Sustituto de %ROWTYPE en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenas, querría saber si existe algún sustituto para la sentencia %ROWTYPE en SQL SERVER me gustaría crear algo así pero no encuentro como hacerlo

```
PROCEDURE mostrar(pdni IN VARCHAR2) is
tupla poblacion_tv%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO tupla
    FROM poblacion
    WHERE dni=borrar.pdni;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(tupla.dni|| ' ' || tupla.nombre);
END borrar;
```

Comment: No, no existe nada de eso. De hecho, un Stored procedure no puede retornar otra cosa que un código de error, si, eventualmente puede ejecutar un sentencia SELECT  y  podrías "capturarla" desde afuera en un INSERT. Si no, las funciones si pueden devolver valores tipo tabla. Opciones hay, lo mejor sería que definas exactamente lo que quieres hacer, y eventualmente la comunidad te podría dar alternativas. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

No existe una funcion **%ROWTYPE** en sql server lo que tienes que hacer es guardar sus datos en variables o puede crear una variable de tabla de la siguiente manera:

```
declare @variable tabla (col1 int,col2 int)
insert into @Fields
select col1,col2
from tabla1
SELECT * from @variable
```

o declarando las varibles de esta forma:

```
DECLARE @External_ID                AS BIGINT = NULL;
DECLARE @PlatformID                 AS INT = NULL;
DECLARE @ActorIDOfReseller          AS INT = NULL;
DECLARE @ActorIDOfClient            AS INT = NULL;
DECLARE @ActorIDOfExtension         AS INT = NULL;
DECLARE @CallType                   AS NCHAR (10) = NULL;
DECLARE @CallInitiatedDate          AS DATE = NULL;
DECLARE @CallInitiatedTimeHH24MI    AS TIME (0) = NULL;
DECLARE @TimePeriodID               AS INT = NULL;
DECLARE @CallAnswered               AS DATETIME = NULL;
DECLARE @CallAnsweredYN             AS BIT = NULL;
DECLARE @CallDispositionID          AS INT = NULL;
DECLARE @CountryID                  AS INT = NULL;
DECLARE @CallPrefixID               AS INT = NULL;
DECLARE @FromNumber                 AS VARCHAR (32) = NULL;
DECLARE @ToNumber                   AS VARCHAR (80) = NULL;
DECLARE @CallDuration               AS INT = NULL;
DECLARE @CallCostToExtension        AS DECIMAL (10, 6) = NULL;
DECLARE @CallCostToClient           AS DECIMAL (10, 6) = NULL;
DECLARE @CallCostToReseller         AS DECIMAL (10, 6) = NULL;
DECLARE @CallCostToAdmin            AS DECIMAL (10, 6) = NULL;
DECLARE @Flow                       AS VARCHAR (3) = NULL;
DECLARE @CallStart                  AS DATETIME = NULL;
DECLARE @MoneyUnit                  AS VARCHAR (32) = NULL;
DECLARE @Prefix                     AS VARCHAR (32) = NULL;
DECLARE @External_CallID            AS VARCHAR (255) = NULL;
```